# AVCaptureDevice auto brightness levels?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I'm currently using an `AVCaptureSession` to take photos with the camera.

I'm using:

```
 device.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = YES;
 device.whiteBalanceMode = AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance;
```

However this doesn't particularly work well in low light situations, the `previewLayer` is pretty dark compared to the default camera app or Instagram's camera.

Am I missing some settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized certain `sessionPreset` aren't supported, needed to use `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` to get `automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable` working.